# How can I use Pixel 4 (Or any Android device that supports Face ID) in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio 3.6.2 and have Android R preview installed. Running Android Emulator 30.0.5. When I try to create a virtual device (From AVD) Pixel 4 is not listed.

I have followed the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createavd) on setting up a new emulator and have read this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/dj4vmq/face_biometric_testing_in_emulator/) which links to [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140498432). Someone posted that it might land late this year. But I have an immediate need to test Face ID. Is it possible to use the Pixel 4 in the Android Emulator?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's listed. You'll have to just make a custom pixel 4 with that hardware profile. And there will be no skin. The 3 is too small for the 4.

Comment: The main intention of the question is to use the Face ID of pixel 4. That's a software feature. With custom hardware profile, we can have pixel 4 like emulator but the software will not be there. So, I think, it would require a physical device to have this feature.

Comment: Good suggestion but as Ifta intimated I would like to use the actual pixel 4 in the emulator.