# How to get Pixel 5 emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a flutter app that builds and runs fine on Pixel 4a, but apparently fails to start on Pixel 5. I want to test this on a Pixel 5 emulator, but I can't find how to add it to Android Studio anywhere.

I downloaded the preview release of Android Studio and followed the other steps in the link in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61214133/how-can-i-use-pixel-4-or-any-android-device-that-supports-face-id-in-android-s#_=_), but there is no Pixel 5 there.

Any ideas?

Comment: This problem is ongoing with the latest Android Studio (version 4.2 beta 6).

Answer (score 5):

I just created a profile. In Android Studio:

- Open AVD manager
- Click New Hardware Profile
- Enter suitable device name e.g. "Pixel 5 API 30"
- Screen size is 6.0", Resolution is 1080 x 2340
- In the Default Skin dropdown, try Pixel 4 XL (this adds the black surround to the AVD. Note that if you use "No skin", it doesn't add the surround shape to the resulting AVD, but you get a useful heading at the top showing its name)
- I accepted the rest of the defaults
- Click Finish
- Click Next to get to System Image dialog
- Select suitable image e.g. R - API 30
- Click Next
- Click Finish

Answer (score 3):

It appears that there is no great option to get a Pixel 5 emulator. Google's document, titled *[Set up Android Emulator to run Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/get#on_emulator)* does not mention the Pixel 5, and [the emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator) has not been updated since the release of the Pixel 5.

You may be able to access one through a service like [Corellium](https://corellium.com/), or, [create a custom hardware profile](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createhp) in Android Studio.

Comment: Ideally I find a way to do this without paying for a third party service.

Comment: @DanielPorteous I've added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) has an emulator for Pixel 5.

However, it does not have an emulator for Pixel 5a (which I just bought).
I will try creating a new hardware profile for my 5a...

Comment: I have that version and am not seeing a pixel_5 skin